# RTK-query: how to have the fixedCacheKey approach also for useLazyQuery?

Tags: reactjs, rtk-query

reading the [documentation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/mutations) I saw that mutations can share their result using the fixedCacheKey option:

> RTK Query provides an option to share results across mutation hook instances using the fixedCacheKey option. Any useMutation hooks with the same fixedCacheKey string will share results between each other when any of the trigger functions are called. This should be a unique string shared between each mutation hook instance you wish to share results.

I have a GET api call that I need to invoke using the `trigger` method of the `useLazyQuery` hook, but I need to exploit its booleans (isSuccess, isError, etc...) in many places. Is it possible to have the same behaviour for the `useLazyQuery` hooks ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up implementing a custom hook to handle this scenario

```js
// This is the custom hook that wrap the useLazy logic
const useCustomHook = () => {
  const [trigger] = useLazyGetItemQuery();
  const result = apiSlice.endpoints.getItem.useQueryState(/* argument if any */);

  const handleOnClick = async () => { 
    // The second argument for the trigger is the preferCacheValue boolean
    const { data, error } = await trigger(/* argument if any */, true);

    // Here where I will implement the success/error logic ...
   }

  return { onClick: handleOnClick, result} 
}
```

Setting the `preferCacheValue` at `true` forced the RTQK to return the cached value if present for the lazy I'm using. That allow me both to avoid triggering many API calls.

Once implemented the hook above I can do the following:

```js
// Component that will make the API call
function Header() {
  const { onClick } = useCustomHook();

  return (<Button onClick={onClick}>Click me</Button>);
}

// Component that will use the booleans
function Body() {
  const { result: { isFetching } } = useCustomHook()

  return (<Spin spinning={isFetching}>
            <MyJSX />
          </Spin>);
}
```

With this approach I was able both to centralize the `trigger` logic (e.g. which parameters I have to pass to my trigger function) and exploiting the booleans of that RTKQ hooks in many components.

Answer (score 1):

In RTK-query, queries instances follow this logic in cache (from documentation):

> When you perform a query, RTK Query automatically serializes the request parameters and creates an internal queryCacheKey for the request. Any future request that produces the same queryCacheKey will be de-duped against the original, and will share updates if a refetch is trigged on the query from any subscribed component.

Given that the only way, in different components, to get the same cache entry is to pass the same query parameters. If you have many useLazy in many components, those hooks don't point any cache entry until you fire them (with some parameters).

This is what I can understand from the official docs

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. So I have to re-trigger the lazy to get the booleans ? That will means that also the boolean lifecycle is replayed again. I just need to trigger the GET in one spot while reading the booleans in another spot, like I can do with the mutations using the fixedCacheKey option. I could do that implementing a react context, but I would like to try some rtkq build-in solution first.